# virtualenv venv - установка setuptools и pip в другие директории

Tags: python, openwrt

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с следующей проблемой - установка setuptools и pip в другие директории, после запуска virtualenv venv.

Virtualenv установлен на USB-Флешку и смонтирован в /root/usb
Запуск самой virtualenv производится консольной командой

```
/root/usb/pythonMH/bin/virtualenv venv
```

После чего она пытается установить setuptools и pip.

```
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip... Connection to 192.168.0.82 closed by remote host.
```

И закрывает соединение, из за того, что на openWRT достаточно мало места, примерно 16 мб, из них 3 мб свободно. Надо заставить устанавливать setuptools и pip на USB-Флешку. Как это сделать? Прочитал туториал, но нужного не нашел.

Comment: Думаю, что проще всего - это увеличить объем флешки)

Comment: не совсем понятно, что требуется, ведь флэшка уже примонтирована. перечисленные программы «не хотят» устанавливаться в указанное место, и пытаются установиться куда там в `/usr`?

Comment: @Nexus, *мало места* — это явно про встроенный в роутер nand-flash-drive.

Comment: @alexander barakin, Тогда в роутере Python ну вообще не в тему

Comment: @Nexus: ну, автору вопроса виднее, нужен ли ему `python` в роутере или нет. @Insider: мне кажется, хорошо бы было привести конкретный пример выполняемой команды и её вывод. кстати, вы про переменную окружения (pythonpath или как там она звучит?) не забываете?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin переменная не забыта. Куда происходит сама установка я не знаю. То что написано в моем вопросе, 1. строка - запуск команды, последующие строки вывод. На всякий случай могу попробовать запустить это все в verbose.

Comment: @Nexus Увеличить место в роутере я не могу. Пока что все это тесты, будет ли все так работать или нет. Если удастся, все будет работать через API

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - попробовал запустить через `/root/usb/pythonMH/bin/virtualenv -v venv` установка проиходит в `/usr/lib/python2.7 `

Comment: @Insider, ну, значит, надо смотреть в документации `virtualenv`, как задать другой каталог для установки пакетов (setuptools и pip — это же пакеты, насколько я понимаю). по идее, это может быть либо доп. параметр, либо переменная окружения, либо строчка в каком-нибудь конф. файле.

Comment: @Insider: возможно, [этот вопрос и ответы на него](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20952797/4827341) могут быть полезны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим путем:

Скачал по отдельность setuptools и pip по ссылкам - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip и https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools.

На всякий случай еще раз перепроверил PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=/root/usb/pythonMH/lib/python/
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

и произвел установку пакетов по выбранному пути

```
python setup.py install --home=/root/usb/pythonMH
```